# Regex to check if the file format is as expected in C#

Tags: c#, regex

My input would be a list of filenames with complete path and I need to extract only the items whose filenames strictly suit the below filename format.

Generic filename format.

```
 **c:\My\Path\To\File\fileName_YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS.ext**
```

I have tried following regex pattern but i still see some noise.

```
string regexPattern = @"fileName_[2-9][0-9]{3}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]_[0-2][0-9]-[0-5][0-9]-[0-5][0-9]\.ext$"
```

Let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: Well, there's no `^` at the start, for one thing. I'd split off the actual filename off from the path and _then_ do the pattern check.

Comment: *"i still see some noise"*  - what exactly? Can you show some examples?

Comment: Ah. He also didn't escape his dot.

Comment: No underscore after filename and not the same case for fileName

Comment: I advise you to just dump your regex into one of many available online regex validators and fiddle with it until it works. This really isn't a deep enough issue to warrant a question here, IMO.

Comment: @sinsedrix the case issue, at least, is something that warrants a shackoverflow question; it can be solved with the regexoptions given to the actual regex object creation.

Comment: What format is the list in? Is it a big string with a CR/LF between each file or are you already splitting the list by line and then processing each string through the regex?

Answer (score 3):

Why use regex when you can use `DateTime`s built in parser for this:

```
string input = c:\My\Path\To\File\fileName_YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS.ext;
string filename = Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension(input);

string[] parts = filename.Split('_');
if (parts.Length != 3) { /*Invalid*/ }

if (Path.GetExtension(input) != "ext") { /*Invalid*/ }

if (parts[0] != "filename") { /*Invalid*/ }

DateTime dt;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(parts[1] + "_" + parts[2], "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)) 
{ /*Invalid*/ }

//IsValid
```

Comment: I like this one as it avoids dealing with date parsing; but I would drop the split for a regex approach for the common parts: `var match  = Regex.Match(Path.GetFileName(input) ?? "", @"^(?<filename>.*?)(?<datetime>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})(?<extension>.*?)$");`; later you can do `match.Groups["datetime"].Value`

Comment: Heh. Very complete, yes. I'd personally just substring on the index of the first `_` rather than using Split, since it's bound to be more efficient, especially since you concat the last two parts afterwards anyway. It'd need more code though.

Comment: @Nyerguds Dmitry Bychenko  has done the same as me except substringing as you suggest

Comment: Since this is C# I'm gonna go ahead and assume the name is case insensitive (in fact the path there will not match, using your method), so make these parts[0] and extension checks actual `.Equals()` calls with the IgnoreCase rule.

Comment: @Nyerguds It is only a demo of what can be done, obviously I'd use those checks or `ToUpper` the strings but I'm not going to write every single possibility than can come out of the code.

Comment: This is a simple ascii example, but do not assume ToUpper before compares make stuff case insensitive. You'd be surprised at the mess you can get into if you assume that in some languages. String.Equals has case insensitivity options though.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite a thing to create a *regular expression* to validate `Date`, just imagine *leap year*. Why not just validate *extension*, *prefix* and *suffix*?
When validating the *suffix* it's very convenient to use `DateTime.TryParse`:

```
  String path = @"c:\My\Path\To\File\fileName_2016-02-29_23-56-59.ext";

  // extension ".ext"
  String ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
  // file name - "fileName_2016-02-29_23-56-59"
  String fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
  // filename prefix "filename"
  String prefix = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf('_'));
  // filename suffix "2016-02-29_23-56-59"
  String suffix = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf('_') + 1);

  DateTime dt;

  bool valid = ext.Equals(".ext", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
               prefix.Equals("fileName") &&
               DateTime.TryParseExact(suffix, 
                 "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss", 
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                 DateTimeStyles.None, 
                 out dt);
```

Comment: To be fair, files of such a format are more likely to be files created _on_ these dates, than files to read dates _from_. The question is about matching a pattern, not extracting dates from file names.

Comment: @Nyerguds: I think the question is about *validating* ("check if the file format is as expected") with *regular expression* being a proposed method (which, IMHO, is not the best choice). That's why in my answer I've put a validation without regular expression.

Comment: True. You didn't account for the case insensitivity of windows file systems though. I suggest `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`.

Comment: @Nyerguds: Thank you! I've edited the answer with `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`

Comment: You only did it for the extension though ;)

Comment: @Nyerguds: the question *doesn't provide* any information about `fileName` (is `FileNAme` considered be right or wrong name), that's why I've put just `Equals`;

Comment: Which is why I specifically mentioned the case insensitivity of _the windows file system itself_.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for:

```
fileName_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}\.ext$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vX8oZ5/1).
This will work for:

```
fileName_1234-12-12_12-12.ext
fileName_1234-12-12_12-12.ext2  (bad extension)
fileName_1234-12-12_12-1234.ext (longer numbers)
/fileName_1234-12-12_12-12.ext/anythingelse (not at the right place)
```

Comment: Less accurate than the original in its date/time format checking though.

Comment: @Nyerguds: True, but the filenames do come from somewhere. Not everything should be done with regular expressions (ie assuming that the filenames have a correct date in them might be appropriate).

Comment: You also forgot the 'seconds' part of the time stamp, and your regex WILL match files that start with text before the "filename" part.

Comment: Is `fileName_2016-99-56_47-93.ext` a *valid* file? I doubt: there's no `99th` month, `56th` day etc. Actually, validating *dates* with *regular expressions* is a challenging task

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: See my first comment. The filenames do not come out of the blue and I know that with this expression you will have a lot of *false positives* - however doing everything with regex might not be your best bet.

Comment: @Jan Good point. It will also match all filenames starting with stuff before the "filename" part though.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are searching for?

```
string regexPattern = @"\\filename_[2-9]\d{3}-[0-1]\d-[0-3]\d_[0-2]\d-[0-5]\d-[0-5]\d\.ext$"
```

---

Changes were made to answer the comment, thank you.

Comment: Nope. Didn't escape the dot before the extension, and doesn't check if the filename start is actually the start of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a solution that check that the filename doesn't start with garbage. Here's my shot at it:

```
\\\w+_[2-9]\d{3}-[0-1]\d-[0-3]\d_[0-2]\d-[0-5]\d-[0-5]\d\.ext
```

It starts to check for the backslash before the filename, and then it's pretty basic matching.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kM2nQ5/1).

Comment: It's not hard, though. This is a C# question, not just a regex one. Just split off the filename beforehand and check on only that, and make sure the regex is surrounded by `^$`.

Comment: @Nyerguds Hmm... Adding a `\\` at the beginning of a regex, or coding to do that... I think I'd go with my suggestion ;)

Comment: It assumes the given filename always contains a path, though. Might not be the case.

Comment: @Nyerguds True, but the requirements given state that a path is present. If not, a word boundary check `\b` at the beginning would do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your REGEX is written correctly? The format you specify is: `**c:\My\Path\To\File\fileName_YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS.ext**` while expression you check against is: `@"filename[2-9][0-9]{3}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]_[0-2][0-9]-[0-5][0-9]-[0-5][0-9].ext$"`

It seems you are missing an underscore.

Otherwise at first glance the expression seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers flowing in here... none of them seem complete though.

```
String path = @"c:\My\Path\To\File\fileName_YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS.ext"
String filename = new FileInfo(path).Name
String regexPattern = @"^filename_[2-9]\d{3}-[0-1]\d-[0-3]\d_[0-2]\d-[0-5]\d-[0-5]\d\.ext$"
Boolean isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(filename, regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

That ought to cover everything.

Answer (score 0):

For those who doesn't prefer to use Regex on this kind of situation, I would like to share different behavior of DateTime.TryParseExact function.

```
        Func<string, string, bool> CheckFileFormat = (fileName, fileMask) =>
        {
            DateTime parsedFileDate;                
            return DateTime.TryParseExact(fileName, fileMask, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedFileDate);
        };


        string FileNameFormat = "'My_File_Name_'yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss'.csv'";
        string FileName = "My_File_Name_2017-10-11_15-46-16.csv";

        if (CheckFileFormat(FileName,FileNameFormat))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"file matches");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("no match!");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```